# Sort TreeMap based on a Enum

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I've a TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<String, List<MyObject>> myTreeMap = new TreeMap<String, List<MyObject>>(new MyComparator());
```

I want to sort this TreeMap based on order of an `enum`.

**MyActionEnum**:

```
public enum MyActionEnum implements Serializable {

    ADD("Add"),
    UPDATE("Update"),
    DELETE("Delete");

    private String action;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    MyActionEnum(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public String get() {
        return this.action;
    }

}
```

Such that in my TreeMap, order should be *Add, Update, Delete*.

**MyComparator:**

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // how to compare here based on enum.
    }
}
```

Comment: If you can use `MyActionEnum` instances as keys directly instead of strings, then you won't have to implement any custom sort (the natural order of enums is the order in which the constants are declared).

Comment: You'll first want to explain what's actually in that TreeMap, and what you think sorting looks like for that data, and then why you think using enums (which are not in the TreeMap) during the comparison pass would make sense.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Seems well-defined: *"order should be `Add`, `Update`, `Delete`"*, which means that the keys (type `String`) are the `action` values of the enums, and that the sort order should be the enum order (`ordinal`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a way to lookup the enum value from the key. Best way to do that is a method on the enum itself, so it's reusable:

```java
public static MyActionEnum fromAction(String action) {
    for (MyActionEnum e : values())
        if (e.action.equals(action))
            return e;
    if (action == null)
        throw new NullPointerException("Action is null");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown action: " + action);
}
```

<sup>*If there were a lot of enum values, you'd want to replace the sequential search done here with a Map lookup.*</sup>

You can then use that in the `compare()` method:

```java
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return Integer.compare(MyActionEnum.fromAction(o1).ordinal(),
                           MyActionEnum.fromAction(o2).ordinal());
}
```